# Crystal Report : How to link from 1 report to another report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, reporting, report

I am using Crystal Reports with C# programming language.
I want to open another report by clicking on link eg. I show Invoice's Summary like its number (named InvNo), date, items and TotalAmount.
Now I would like to open another report when user clicks on InvNo column. If user clicks on Invno 0001 then another report should be opened showing Item-wise details...

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two 'linking' options:

1. use an 'on-demand' subreport - this is a report embedded in another report.  it is NOT generated until its link is clicked.  'standard' subreports are generated at the same time as the 'main' report.  in either case, a subreport can NOT contain another subreport.
2. create a hyperlink to another report by setting a field's Hyperlink property (choose the 'A Website on the Internet' option).  if you create a conditional formula (the 'X+2' button), you'll have more control over the URL that is generated.  you'll probably want to create a controller page (like 'view_report.aspx') that parses the querystring for the report's id (id=234), opens the report, authenticates, add parameters (country=USA&region=MN&start_date=20110501), generates the report, then returns it.

Use option 1 for the summary, then use option 2 for the item's details.

If you are using BusinessObjects Enterprise, use [UrlReporting](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2/en/en/BOE_SDK/boesdk_java_dg_doc/doc/boesdk_java_dg/Report_Linking.html) for option 2.

Comment: I work in desktop base program. so i want to hyperlink it but the option 2 is for website. beside how can i use conditional formula? Is there any tutorial about it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [subreports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227520%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) functionality is an answer to your question.

You would need to enter a formula that conditionally shows/hide them (they should be hidden by default). Unfortunately I cannot tell you how to do that from the back of my head, since I haven't worked on CR for pretty long time now... Please find few links [here](http://www.google.pl/search?hl=pl&safe=off&q=+site%3asocial.msdn.microsoft.com+showing+and+hiding+subreport+Crystal+Reports#sclient=psy&num=10&hl=pl&safe=off&source=hp&q=site%3asocial.msdn.microsoft.com+showing+and+hiding+subreport+Crystal+Reports&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=site%3asocial.msdn.microsoft.com+showing+and+hiding+subreport+Crystal+Reports&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=82646d270c7a251d).